# How to optimize a TSQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

"activity" is a bit field. I need to set it to true if one of the rows with this client_id has value true

```
SELECT c.client_id, u.branch_id, a.account_id, activity
FROM Clients c INNER JOIN 
      accounts a ON c.id=a.client_id INNER JOIN uso u ON a.uso_id = u.uso_id,
     (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(int,accounts.activity)) as activity, client_id
       FROM accounts GROUP BY client_id) activ
WHERE activ.client_id = c.id
```

This query executes about 2 minutes. Please help me to optimize it.

Comment: `accounts.activity` is a `BIT`, isn't it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems `activity` field is a `BIT` and you cannot do a `MIN` or `MAX` on it.

Instead of this, use `TOP`:

```
SELECT  c.client_id, u.branch_id, a.account_id,
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 activity
        FROM    accounts ai
        WHERE   ai.client_id = c.id
        ORDER BY
                activity DESC
        )
FROM    clients c
JOIN    accounts a
ON      c.id = a.client_id
JOIN    uso u
ON      a.uso_id = u.uso_id
```

Create an index on `accounts (client_id, activity)` for this to work fast.

You may want to read this article:

- [**Minimum and maximum on bit fields: SQL Server**](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/12/minimum-and-maximum-on-bit-fields-sql-server/)

Answer (score -2):

Join is expensive. Instead of Join, use memcache and make separate requests.

Comment: People who down vote my answer seem to be stranger to sql request optimizations.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. However the process is called "query optimization", not "request optimization". If you had read more about it, you, first, would call it properly and, second, would not have given this answer at all.

Comment: By doing "request optimization", I'm doing "query optimization", select are using "WHERE id IN (...)".